# GridView does not show all the rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview

I have a GridView on my form. I've set its DataSource to a DataTable. I retrieve DataTable like this:

```
SELECT AMOUNT, ISSUEDATE,REASON FROM PAYMENTS WHERE 
PENSIONERID=113 ORDER BY ISSUEDATE DESC
```

When I run this query on the server side I get three records. But on my web page the gridview shows only two of them. There's no condition set on the code behind that would cause the gridview to not show any kind of record. After some time when I restart the server I can see the third row in the gridview. Is this a problem related to my IIS? What could be the reason in any case? Thank you.

Here's the GridView and datat loading code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOdanBirm" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPayments_PageIndexChanging" 
    PageSize="3">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ISSUEDATE" HeaderText="Issue date">
            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="70px" />
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AMOUNT" HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="30px" />
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="REASON" HeaderText="REASON" 
            >
            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" />
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#01055E" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
 gvPayments.DataSource=  GetPayments(pensionerID);
 gvPayments.DataBind();
```

Comment: are you using paging? could you please post Gridview code and your data access code

Comment: What is the column datatype for reason?  Is it a text/blob?

Comment: Maybe reason (or some other column) contains Html that is messing up the presentation markup.

Comment: That's a good point. But the thing is the problem goes away if I restart the server

Comment: The server that hosts your site or the database?

Comment: The server hosts both database and the website

Comment: seems like method GetPayments cache data rows in memory, after reset it reload them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the following?

1. Look at the source code of the page generated when the row does not appear... is the row not making it into the page at all?  Or is it just not displaying for some reason?
2. Can you get the third row when it isn't appearing by moving to the next page?  Temporarily take out the paging commands from the aspx code to see if that resolves it.
3. Check that the server is up to date with all service packs, etc. for the database, OS, and IIS.
4. What version of IIS are you running?  What server OS?
5. Can you post the code behind `gvPayments_PageIndexChanging`, and any code you have behind building the gridview?
6. What browser are you using to view the results?  When you get the error, can you try another browser or another machine?  And do you get the same result?
7. Forgot a biggie... Can you break after `gvPayments.DataSource=  GetPayments(pensionerID);`?  Are you getting all three rows retrieved from the database?  Maybe your problem isn't in the aspx code, but in the data you're getting back to bind to.

Will think more while you post those.

Comment: 1. I check for that and the html source does not contain that row at all. 2. The size of the grid is three, so no pages appear because there're basically 2 rows in the grid. 4.The server is Win server 2003. 6. I use IE7 to view the results. I checked it on Mozilla but I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Is it SQL Server?  Run profiler and see what select statement is actually being passed into SQL Server.  You can copy it into Management Studio and execute to see if you get 2 or 3 records.  No, it is probably not running the exact select statement that you pass into it, and the only way to know what it IS running is to profile it...

This will tell you for certain whether it is SQL related or the GridView causing the problem...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but I'm sure there is parallel functionality.  You need to find out what the statement is that's actually being executed.